# proof of set operation discrete math

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if $$a=\{3n \mid n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$$ and $$b=\{3^{2m}\mid m \in \mathbb{Z}^+\},$$ prove that $b$ is a subset of $a$.

I think the question is wrong. I think $a$ should be a subset of $b$.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, it's asking you to prove that all positive multiples of $9$ are positive multiples of $3$.  Which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ cannot be a subset of $B$. For example $6$ is a multiple of $3$, but $6$ is not a multiple of $9$. However, anything that is a multiple of $9$, is a multiple of $3$, since $9 = 3^2$.

An accepted proof is as follows.
$$A = \{3n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\} \\ B = \{9m : m \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$$

Let $x$ be in $B$. Then there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x=9k$. But this is $x=3 (3k)$. Since $k$ is a positive integer, so is $3k$. Let $j=3k$. So there is $j \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x=3j$. But this satisfies the definition of $A$, so $x$ is in $A$.

Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that $B \subset A$.

Comment: Maybe the problem was edited after you answered, but right now it has $3^{2m}$ where you have $9m$.